# How can I insert values in to javascript object by using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have and object and i want to insert the values in it dynamically.

```
      var mergTr={}; //object
       for(dd in dispID)
      {
        var dataID=displayObj[dispID[dd]]; 
        if(dataObj[dataID])
        {   var flag=0;  
            var valObj=dataObj[dataID];
            var Class2 = (clsNo==0)?"even":"odd";
            var cl_id=valObj["client_id"];
            var dataId=dataID;
            var columnName=valObj["fieldname"];
            var valFilterObj={0:"",1:"",2:columnName,3:dataObj[dataID]["filter_type"],4:"",5:dataObj[dataID]["filter_auto"]}; 
            if(flag==0){
                for(vv in valFilterObj){
                     tr=$("<tr/>");
                     mergTr=tr;
                     tr.addClass(clsNo);
                     var td=$("<td/>");
                     td.append(columnName);
                     tr.append(td);
                }
                $.merge(mergTr,tr);
            }
        }
      }
```

I want to insert 'tr' in object as looping.But i dont know how to do it. $.merge is not working. If i will directly assign the 'tr' then it replaces the old 'tr' value.
Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: You can assign values to your objet like this: var mergTr={}; //object

     mergTr.flag = 0;
     mergTr.valObj = 'data';
     ...

Comment: @Steve sorry i didnt understand it. can you pls explain it or can you give me any reference link.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a list of `<tr>` you should have an array instead of object.

```
var mergTr={}; // {} denotes object
var mergTr=[]; // [] denotes array
```

You can push the values in array as `mergTr.push(trObject);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use array to store tr and in **for loop** use **var** to redefine the tr locally then add to array.

```
var mergTr=[];

// the initial code 
// ...
       if(flag==0){
                for(vv in valFilterObj){
                  var tr=$("<tr/>");
                    // Here the old tr is being re-assigned  mergTr=tr;
                     tr.addClass(clsNo);
                     var td=$("<td/>");
                     td.append(columnName);
                     tr.append(td);
                    mergTr.push(tr);
                }

            }
```

Comment: yes i can do it. But when this function returns object to the original function from where this function is called, i need to merge this object with one more object also. So is it possible to merge and array with object?

Comment: The return object is going to be an array, and if the other object is array then you can use merge but the merge will simply add both of them together. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?  This function just creates rows elements and returns, then what next? how are you trying to use it?